# Set multiple textview android in single listview

Tags: android

I am able to send and receive message xmpp client and display them in listview in corresponding layouts. When i send or receive message. I get both the sent and received message combined in a single textview on different layouts.I need to display them in different  layouts's textview. i want to display received message in 1 layout's textview and sent message in another layouts textview correspondingly.

Kindly guide me in this issue..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you post an example of what you want this to look like? Your explanation is not that good im afraid. I think you are wanting to put sent messages in one textview, and received messages in another? If so, just make sure the ID's of the TextView are different, and grab which one you need

Comment: I am sorry for not properly framing my question.. I have 2 different layouts and each layout is having a textview. I need to call that corresponding layouts based on send or receive message. How can i achive it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Perform this below way:-

```
package com.aman.sample.bubblelist;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Main extends Activity {

    String[] data = { "Sample User Data ", "Sample User Data ",
            "Sample User Data ", "Sample User Data ", "Sample User Data ",
            "Sample User Data ", "Sample User Data ", "Sample User Data ",
            "Sample User Data ", "Sample User Data ", "Sample User Data ",
            "Sample User Data ", "Sample User Data ", "Sample User Data ",
            "Sample User Data ", "Sample User Data " };
    Drawable[] usrimg = null;
    String bgimg = "", _user = "", _pass = "";
    int odd_resID, even_resID;
    ListView myList;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // finding the list view
        myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myList);
        myList.setAdapter(new MyCustomAdapter());
        myList.setCacheColorHint(0);

    }

    class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return data.length;
        }

        @Override
        public String getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public int getViewTypeCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return data.length;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            View row;
            int _intPosition = getItemViewType(position);
            String even_color, odd_color;
            SharedPreferences prefList = getSharedPreferences("PrefsFile",
                    MODE_PRIVATE);
            ;
            even_color = prefList.getString("even_bubble_color", "pink");
            odd_color = prefList.getString("odd_bubble_color", "green");
            int even_color_id = getResources().getIdentifier(even_color,
                    "drawable", "com.teks.chilltwit"), odd_color_id = getResources()
                    .getIdentifier(odd_color, "drawable", "com.teks.chilltwit");
            ImageView even_view, odd_view;

            if (_intPosition % 2 == 0) {
                row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row_layout_even, parent,
                        false);
                TextView textLabel = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.text);

                textLabel.setText(data[position]);

            } else {
                row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row_layout_odd, parent,
                        false);
                TextView textLabel = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.text);

                textLabel.setText(data[position]);
            }

            return (row);
        }
    }

}
```